# Writing a Program that Divides 2 user outputs without crashing

Tags: c#

I recently started taking a intro to programming course that programs in C# and I am stuck on an assignment that asks us to "Write a program which takes two user input values and divides them  without crashing on a divide by zero error.
Create a prompt asking the user to input two integer values.
Assign each input to its own variable.
Create a custom method which takes the second number input and divides it by the first number input.
Call the custom method from your Main() method.
Your program should not crash if a divide by zero error occurs"

I am still working through the last bit of notes we have for the topic, but I feel like I don't even have a solid foundation to start on! If someone could provide an example for me, that would be great! (I am more of a visual learner rather than take notes and execute)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I provided an answer for how to handle exceptions such as a divide by 0 exception, in the future, try to ask more specific questions (i.e., rather than asking for a general example, ask for an example of something specific, such as handling an  exception/error) and provide specific details about what you are confused by or having trouble with.  These will make it easier for people to provide good answers that can help you learn rather than just doing something for you.

Comment: Are the inputs integers or floats?

Answer (score 1):

As like most programming questions, this question has more than one answer. Also, you did not specified what needs to happen when 0 is given as input2

Here is my answer. (It continously asks a new input for input2)

```
public static int Divide()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter first number");
        var val = Console.ReadLine();
        int input1 = Convert.ToInt32(val);

        Console.WriteLine("Enter second number");
        val = Console.ReadLine();
        int input2 = Convert.ToInt32(val);

        while (input2 == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Second number can't be 0");
            val = Console.ReadLine();
            input2 = Convert.ToInt32(val);
        }
        return input1 / input2;
    }
```

You can call custom function "Divide" by using:

```
Console.WriteLine("Result is : " + Divide());
```

in your Main function

And lastly, I advise you to take a look to "Exceptions" and "Try-Catch" blocks for simpler answer.

Comment: This **will** crash if the user inputs a character or non-integer value.

Comment: I think this is a collage or coding camp question, not a real life situation, so inputs will be integers (with 0 included of course).
But you are right :) it certainly will

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to write code that will not crash on a divide by 0 exception, you should consider using try-catch statement. This would look something like this

```
try {
    divide(num1, num2); // method that divides values
} 
catch (DivideByZeroException) {
   /* exception handling code here */
}
```

Comment: Using exceptions for behavior that is expected (user inputting zero) is not recommended. A simple `if` statement will suffice.